# Can I indent pv's output (or of any command that outputs CRs)?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, carriage-return

With `pv`, I can show a progress bar for anything I pipe through it, for example

```
echo 1234567890 | pv --size 10 >/dev/null
```

It prints a nice progress bar that gets updated whenever more data comes through (which should be really fast in this example of course and not very useful since the data only gets to `/dev/null`).

Can I somehow indent the output of `pv`? Imagine something like a script that goes through a list of all invitees to my party, calls them on the phone, talks to them, and writes to the console, if they want to come to the party or not:

```
echo "The next person on the list is Berta." ;\
echo "    Calling Berta..."; \
echo "    Berta answered the phone. Talking..."; \
printf "    "; \
for word in TALK TALK TALK TALK TALK; do 
    printf $word; sleep 1; 
done | pv --size 20 --width 100 >/dev/null; \
echo "    Berta said she would come to the party."
```

If you try that, you will see, that the *first* output of the pv progress bar will start after the four blanks printed by printf, but already the first update will jump back to the line beginning (with CR, probably), resulting in the following output afterwards:

```
The next person on the list is Berta.
    Calling Berta...
    Berta answered the phone. Talking...
20.0 B 0:00:05 [3.53 B/s] [======================================================>] 100%            0:01
    Berta said she would come to the party.
```

Is there any way to prevent pv (or any other command issuing a CR) to jump back to the line beginning? Output of long-running commands like the example would be so much more readable indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution specific to `pv`: use `-F`/`--format` and include four leading blanks in the format string.

> `-F`, `--format FORMAT`
> Ignore the options `-p`, `-t`, `-e`, `-r`, `-a`, `-b`, `-T`, and `-A`, and instead use the format string `FORMAT` to determine the output format. See the FORMATTING section […].

<sup>(source: [`man 1 pv`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pv.1.html))</sup>

I won't cite the FORMATTING section here. See `man 1 pv`.

---

Example:

```
echo "The next person on the list is Berta." ;\
echo "    Calling Berta..."; \
echo "    Berta answered the phone. Talking..."; \
for word in TALK TALK TALK TALK TALK; do 
    printf '%s' "$word"; sleep 1; 
done | pv -F '    %p' --size 20 >/dev/null; \
echo "    Berta said she would come to the party."
```

Comment: Wow. I thought I had read the manpage.